# Get Value from object in html MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

How I can get an object in HTML?

I have this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Product.Keys.Where(x => x.TransactionID == model.TransactionID))
```

but here I have an object, and I want to display only one value.

I tried something like this:

```
@{
    var key = model.Product.Keys.Where(x => x.TransactionID == model.TransactionID);
}
```

but model name doesn't exist in the current context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to use `Model`

```
@{
    var key = Model.Product.Keys.Where(x => x.TransactionID == Model.TransactionID);
}
```